# In Python why does the variable specified inside the loop has length 1 whereas the other outside the loop has its original length?

Tags: python, variables, string-length, variable-length-array, variable-length

As declaring a variable1 inside for loop I have assigned some string to it>>>whereas given another variable2 .....when provided with the output it shows variable1 len is 1 and variable2 has 8 how does that work???

```
    for variable1 in "something is here please help":
        print(variable1)
    variable2 = "abcdefgh"
    print(len(variable1))
    print(len(variable2))
```

Comment: `variable1` is used to iterate over a string, so it holds one character at a time. You never assign any long string to `variable1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop is used for iterating over a sequence (that is either a list, a tuple, a dictionary, a set, or a string). In your case the sequence is a String( "something is here please help") and the iterator should go through all the letters: 's','o','m','t'... That's why its length is 1 which mean one single character. Please refer to: [https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp#:~:text=A%20for%20loop%20is%20used,other%20object%2Dorientated%20programming%20languages](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp#:%7E:text=A%20for%20loop%20is%20used,other%20object%2Dorientated%20programming%20languages).

Comment: Note that there are infinitely more kinds of iterables than just lists, tuples, dicts, sets and strings.

Comment: Any custom class you write can be made iterable, that alone allows for infinite iterable types. Not to mention that there are a few more already built in.

Comment: Ok now i see what you mean but the basic ones are mentioned above : Lists, tuples, Dictionaries, Strings and Sets. Iterables are in the matter of fact infinit.